# SQL Server 2008 sys.objects equivalent to sysobjects.uid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-view

Does anyone know how to get an equivalent of the SQL Server 2000 `sysobjects` `uid` column from the 2005+ `sys.objects` (or another) view?

I am trying to convert this code, as we are getting rid of all `sysobjects` references.

```
DECLARE GETOBJECTS CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NAME, UID FROM SYSOBJECTS
WHERE TYPE IN ('U','P')
    AND UID <> 1
    AND LOWER(RTRIM(NAME)) NOT LIKE 'PB%'
```

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UID** refers to the User ID of the owner of the object...

In SQL 2005 and SQl 2008, you can find it in

```
sys.sysobjects
```

field name **UID**

[Sys.sysobjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

UID =1 is the dbo user.

So to use the routines and tables views and filter out dbo, try the following code

```
select Routine_name as Name, specific_schema as user 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where specific_schema <> 'dbo'
UNION
select Table_name as Name, specific_schema as user 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where specific_schema <> 'dbo'
```

Comment: Isn't this one of the tables that will go away in the new release?  I am hoping to use one of the views that will continue to be available into the future.

Comment: Sys.Sysobjects is a compatibility view for 2005 and 2008.   Not sure if they will support it in Denali and future versions...  The documenation on the ROUTINES view for Denali seems to imply the SYS view collection will be around though...  I modified my answer to show how to get same info from the ROUTINES view

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it out on Monday and let you know the result!  I have run out of time today.

Answer (score 0):

To get all objects that aren't owned by the `dbo` principal, do something like this:

```
select name, object_id
from sys.objects
where principal_id not in
(
    select principal_id
    from sys.database_principals
    where name = 'dbo'
)
```

Comment: the uid is referring the id of the owner of the table, unfortunately, this would return the name and id of every object, but what I am looking for is the name of every object not owned by dbo (uid = 1)

Comment: @Kevin check out my edit.  I have put up a query that selects the name and id of all objects that aren't owned by the `dbo` principal.